# TLS record layer implementation

Tags: tls

I have some general confusion about TLS protocol. One question is about session id. Should a session id inside the TLS hellomessage have a session id length field? I do not read anything about it in the request for comments on TLS. If there a client is not resuming a prior session then it says it should remain 'empty'. What does that mean? Perhaps id session length (itself a 1 byte field) of zero, followed by no session id field? Or a session id field with zero byte? Or should I remove the session id fields completely?

Additionally in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361617/how-to-format-a-tls-record-to-be-sent-with-winsock-for-https I have received TLS fatal alerts 70, regardless of the protocol combinations I offer? If I reverse the byte ordering of the plain text I get a fatal alert for 10?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three (soon four) versions of TLS, each with its own RFC (plus a retrospective historical one for SSLv3), but at the basic record level for unencrypted records -- which is, initial handshake records through first CCS or alert -- they are the same.

[RFC5246 for TLSv1.2 in the section on ClientHello](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2) defines at the top of page 41 that structure (ClientHello) to include `SessionID session_id`. Similarly for [ServerHello](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.3) at the bottom of page 42. Note that [HelloRequest](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.1) is also classified as a hello message (and a handshake message) but does not contain a session_id or indeed any body at all. `SessionID` is defined on page 40 as

```
opaque SessionID<0..32>;
```

You should recognize that syntax as a [variable-length vector previously explained in 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.1) which also explains how the length prefix of every variable-length vector works.

'Empty' means no bytes in the value i.e. a length of zero, encoded as a length prefix of zero followed by no (or equivalently not any) content. If you think about the encodings defined in section 4 it is obvious that you cannot *omit* a field from a fixed structure; some (not all) variable-length fields can be empty, and some (only some) structures have variants where you use only the fields of the one variant applicable in a given situation as specified. However, the extension field in Client or Server Hello is defined as a variable-length sequence of items each of which begins with an explicit (2-byte) type, so you can include or omit, and reorder, extension items within the extensions field -- at least for encoding; whether a peer will accept a set of extensions is up to that peer.

If you want to implement TLS you really need to understand the applicable RFC(s) for the version(s) you want 2246/4346/5246, plus several related ones like 3546/4366/6066 for extensions, maybe 4492 (and SEC1 etc) for ECC, maybe added suites like 5288/5289 for GCM, etc.

Comment: Are parts of the record encoded in ascii or simply as numbers?

Comment: @marshalcraft A generic record (headers) no. The optional extensions in ClientHello and ServerHello include Server Name Indication (SNI) which contains DNS name(s) which are a subset of ASCII defined by DNS standards, and Application Layer Protocol Negotiation (ALPN) which contains names that are formally opaque but all actually registered names are short ASCII strings.